# How do I make an album or image popup in lightbox from facebook page tab iframe

Tags: facebook, user-interface, tabs, popup

I may be stupid, but I just don't get this the fb ui calls too well. Let's say my FB page tab shows fine - and it wants to call am image from the page's photos.

Page tab
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Team-Vermont/210976122316498?sk=app_201737266589689

Photo URL
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=211294658951311&set=a.211294338951343.52676.210976122316498&type=3&theater

I tried searching and posting all sorts of code to the page tab, but nothing was going right. All I have now is an onclick popup to an html page on my video 1 link - as a test. But I really want a "highlights" section that the user woud be able to click and have the pic pop up in the FB light box style. I am not a great coder, and I appreciate all your input.

What I am asking for is the code to make this happen, or an example of it happening somewhere so I can look at it and dissect.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image and Video Lightbox in page tab iframe](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8953997/image-and-video-lightbox-in-page-tab-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

You got the answer here, why are you asking again the same question?
[Image and Video Lightbox in page tab iframe](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8953997/image-and-video-lightbox-in-page-tab-iframe)

Comment: I got an answer on using shadowbox - but I am thinking using the FB system for displaying the photos/videos might work. So its sort of a new route. What would help greatly is some code showing a picture popping up on someones iframe tab. That would do it for me - I think I can take it from there.